# Bug in react app only present on nginx webserver, not localhost

Tags: reactjs, nginx

in my react app I've been struggling with a bug that made a map the wrong size on the page. After solving the bug yesterday I've been trying to make the solution work on my server. Using Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx as the webserver serving my /build folder. I tried 'hard resetting' the page by deleting the entire website folder from /var/www, re-cloning from githug and running yarn build again, how ever the bug is still present; but not present in localhost.

My nginx config

```
server {
   root /var/www/<sitepath>/build;
   server_name <siteurl        .;
   index index.html index.htm;
   location / {
       try_files $uri /index.html;
       auth_basic "This site is under development";
       auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
   }
    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
      expires -1;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      expires 1y;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate <pempath>; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key  <pempath>; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam <pempath>; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = <mysite>) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = <mysite>) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


   listen 80;
   server_name <mysite>;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

The rest of the site seems to be working fine, I'm only using nginx as my webserver, no node is being used. I've tried using chrome incognito mode and tested on laptops that have never opened the page before, but the bug is still present. The app was made using create-react-app, I have not ejected the create-react-app. for running the app localhost I've been using `yarn run`

site on the server:
[site on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8cnN.png)

site on localhost
[site on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZvYY.png)

I'd be happy to post any additional config or code that may help solving this issue.

edit:
I've tried doing the same process with deleting the website folder and re-cloning localhost to see if the issue was present then, it was not.